# Exchange Server 2007 - Not Receving Emails

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

We aren't able to receive emails from external sources but:

- Emails internally are working fine (internal to internal)
- Emails being sent out work fine (internal to external)

But, external to internal emails fail. We have tried to do a disk check but it can't even complete a scan (even restarting takes upwards of 8 minutes). But, this is the only solid 'issue' we've found.

We are new to this realm and any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: We are also looking at: http://serverfault.com/questions/30334/exchange-2007-no-inbound-e-mail-any-ideas-why but their solutions have not assisted us yet.

Comment: You should give more data about the situation: your configuration, what have you already tried and which are the outcomes of this research.

Comment: Is there something you're not telling us? There is no possible vaguely sane connection between "emails work internally but not externally" and "better scan my disks" without a long painful story inbetween (or someone so far out of their depth they need to just get in an external consultant). And define "fail" - is there an error bounce? An entry in the event log? Messages stuck in a queue?

Comment: The question refers to disk issues because the linked earlier question was related to backpressure (which was related, in that case, to not enough free disk space, but can be caused by different types of resource exhuastion.) Why they followed that line of reasoning to chkdisk, and what issue(s) they think they've found, are definite unknowns for the rest of us today.

Answer (score 3):

1. Check your MX records; verify that they point to the public IP that your Exchange servers use to listen on port 25.
2. Verify that you can connect to port 25 from an external IP.
3. If that fails, verify that you can connect to port 25 from an internal IP.
4. Read the logs for your SMTP connector that receives mail from the internet. (If you've not already enabled logging, do that.)